# Sort the Inserted data on basis of Time in Ontology Model

Tags: sorting, sparql, ontology, protege

I have an ontology Model. I am inserting integer data in one of the class instance through Sparql update. The model is storing the data randomly with out any order. Now when I want to extract this data through Sparql Query I want it in order of the time of insertion. How could i achieve this? Any idea?

P.S: My ontology Model is made in Protege software.
My Query for inserting Data is below one.

```sql
PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> 
INSERT { 
  ?KPI_Variables test:hasValue_ROB1 10
} WHERE {
  ?KPI_Variables test:hasValue_ROB1 ?Newvalue 
  FILTER(?KPI_Variables= test:Actual_Production_Time)
}
```

And For Getting the data I am using the following Query:

```sql
PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> 
SELECT ?KPI_Variables ?Newvalue WHERE {
  ?KPI_Variables test:hasValue_ROB1 ?Newvalue 
  FILTER(?KPI_Variables = test:Actual_Production_Time)
} LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Can you edit your your question by putting your query? So that people can see your effort and help you.

Comment: Question Edited. Queries Added

Comment: How do you run the INSERT query? In Protege? If so, by which plugin?

Comment: Time of insertion is not SPARQL specific. It just adds triple to the set of existing triples. There might be some triple store specific support, but it's not generic. Obviously, for your case an addition triple with the timestamp of insertion would be necessary - and that has to be done via RDF reification since you want to to make a statement about a statement (resp. RDF triple)

Comment: I am using apacha jena fuseki server to run queries and updates on my ontology model.

Comment: Yes i thought about adding timestamps triples but the problem remain the same that it would add it randomly. For example i have to insert 5 integers at span of 10 sec each so it stores like this [X2, X5, X3, X1, X4](they all are integers and they stores randomly.) Now you want me to insert timestamps at the same time which will also store like this [T5, T3,T4, T2,T1]. Now how would i know that which timestamp is for which integer?

Comment: Each integer will be added by a separate triple, right? Thus, for each triple you add an reifying triple with the timestamp. See the answer from @JoshuaTaylor below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data in RDF is simply triples. There's no notion of *when* a triple is added to a graph.  If you want that kind of information, you'll need to make it explicit in your data model.  SPARQL does include a **now** function that lets you get a timestamp for when a query is run.  That means that you could do something like this:

```sql
prefix  : <urn:ex:>

insert {
  [] :hasSubject ?s ;
     :hasPredicate ?p ;
     :hasObject ?o ;
     :hasTime ?now .
}
where {
    #-- Fake a couple of triples
    values (?s ?p ?o) {
        (:a :p :b)
        (:c :q :d)
    }
    #-- Get the current time
    bind (now() as ?now)
}
```

Now your graph contains data like:

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:> .

[ :hasObject     :d ;
  :hasPredicate  :q ;
  :hasSubject    :c ;
  :hasTime       "2017-04-28T13:32:11.482+00:00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>
] .

[ :hasObject     :b ;
  :hasPredicate  :p ;
  :hasSubject    :a ;
  :hasTime       "2017-04-28T13:32:11.482+00:00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>
] .
```

Which you can query like:

```sql
prefix  : <urn:ex:>

select ?s ?p ?o ?time {
  [] :hasSubject ?s ;
     :hasPredicate ?p ;
     :hasObject ?o ;
     :hasTime ?time
}
order by ?time
```

```
s,p,o,time
urn:ex:c,urn:ex:q,urn:ex:d,2017-04-28T13:32:11.482+00:00
urn:ex:a,urn:ex:p,urn:ex:b,2017-04-28T13:32:11.482+00:00
```

Once you've inserted some things at different times, you'd have different time values, so sorting would be meaningful.  I'd suggest that you don't just reify the triples like I did (and if you are going to go with a straightfoward reification, you should probably use the standard vocabulary for it), but rather have some meaningful structure that actually has timestamps as part of it.